# dead letters encountered error while sending a message

Tags: scala, actor

I am pretty new to Actors was trying them out but I am getting this exception which I don't understand why I am getting it

```
object AskPattern extends App{
  case object AskName

  class Name extends Actor{
    override def receive: Receive = {
      case AskName => sender ! "Helmy"
      case s : String => println(s)
    }
  }
  val systemActor = ActorSystem("AskPattern")
  val actor1 = systemActor.actorOf(Props[Name],"Umair")
  val actor2 = systemActor.actorOf(Props[Name],"Farooq")
  actor2 ! AskName

}
```

Comment: When you send a message from outside of an actor, there is no way to receive an answer. Therefore, the `AskName` message is sent with `DeadLetters` as the sender. When you answer that message it will thus be sent directly to `DeadLetters`. Try sending the first message from within an actor or use the ask pattern as suggested in other answers. See https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html?language=scala#ask-send-and-receive-future for more info.

Comment: Yeah .. make sense as in the main we don't have any context related to actor

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure why are the dead letters generated. But a simple implementation of the ask pattern is

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object AskPattern extends App {
  case object AskName

  class Name extends Actor{
    override def receive: Receive = {
      case AskName => sender ! "Helmy"
      case s : String => println(s)
    }
  }

 implicit val timeout: akka.util.Timeout = Timeout.apply(1,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  val systemActor = ActorSystem("AskPattern")
  val actor1 = systemActor.actorOf(Props[Name],"Umair")
  val actor2 = systemActor.actorOf(Props[Name],"Farooq")

  actor2 ? AskName map { x => println(s"Resolved future $x") }
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/XIg5oJKQT4m5ZgfotDES4A)

Comment: Thanks a lot I later found out why it was throwing that exception, I am sending the first msg to the actor from the main which is not the part of any actor so sending it back a msg through sender ! "Any Msg" causes the exception. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the complete output so we can try to see what happens precisely.

Dead letters means the actor you want to send the message to is not reachable: the message is lost.

First note that: 
The `sender` depends on the context of the last message received. It is not a value but a **function** (it changes each time you receive a message). So please use `sender()` instead of `sender`.

Second note: 
What you try to achieve is known as the **ask pattern**, and akka provides facilities for that. You should take a look at [the documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.5/scala/actors.html#ask-send-and-receive-future).